# Windows Form Buttons in C#

Tags: winforms, button

I am trying to have a button on my C# windows form with a name "Click Me"

It looks like the button text accepts only the words before the space and ignores the rest.
Having:
    this.button_ClickMe.Text = "Click Me";

Displays my button with text "Click" only.

Any idea why? and is there a work-around??

- Ivar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect the button is just too small. Make it bigger, or make set `AutoSize = true` (and place it within a container which has enough space, obviously).

Here's an example which works fine for me:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Form form = new Form {
            Controls = {
                new Button { 
                    Text = "Click Me!", 
                    AutoSize = true,
                    Location = new Point(10, 30)
                },
            }
        };
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

(Admittedly this sample works even with `AutoSize = false`, so I *suspect* you've hard-coded the size somewhere... or your font is bigger. With longer text, it only works with `AutoSize = true` or a manually specified size.)

Answer (score 4):

Button's too small.  Make it slightly bigger.  You can (but shouldn't) but as much text as you want on a button, including whole sections of HitchHiker's Guide to the Galaxy. (was testing to see if there was a limit)

Answer (score 0):

Check the width of the button.